# Linux sysfs gpio: what re-arms interrupt?

Tags: linux, interrupt, gpio, sysfs

The usual way to respond to an edge-triggered GPIO interrupt, using the old sysfs GPIO interface, is like this:

```
repeat forever
    poll() on POLLPRI event on GPIO fd
    lseek() back to 0 on GPIO fd
    read() current state from GPIO fd
```

If I put the code that actually handles the interrupt after the `read()`, is it guaranteed that any new interrupt that happens before `poll()` is called again will cause that next `poll()` to return immediately? In other words, what step re-arms the interrupt? The return from `poll()`, the call to `lseek()`, the call to `read()`, or the next call to `poll()`? If it's the last of these, I don't see any way to guarantee that an interrupt can't get lost.

Also, is it necessary to do the `read()`? I don't care about the state, just the edge event. And if I don't need `read()`, does `lseek()` do anything useful? This is hard to test in real life, because it would require generating interrupts in rapid succession on the existing hardware. None of the docs seem to explain this.

Comment: First of all, do not use sysfs interface. Second, what kernel version you are talking about? We can check the code and see what happens there.

Comment: This https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/kernfs/file.c#L943 and this https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/kernfs/file.c#L801 will answer to the `lseek()` question.

Comment: This shows what happens when new interrupt (event) is coming https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/kernfs/file.c#L913. AFAIU when you read the value, you will read the actual state (which may be different to what triggered the poll). Which means that read of event makes a little sense.

Comment: I'm stuck with 4.0.0, which is why I'm using sysfs. I don't know my way around the kernel at all, so I couldn't figure out anything from those bits of code, least of all when the interrupt is re-armed. Although there is a comment in the code implying that it really is necessary to do an lseek and a read. I read something somewhere on the advantages of /dev/gpiochip which said "The polling process to catch events (interrupts from GPIO lines) is reliable" which leads me to fear that there may be some intrinsic problem with /sys/class/gpio that makes an occasional missed interrupt unavoidable.

Comment: v4.0?! (There was no v4.0.0) It's very strange. But okay, it's not the main issue we are discussing here.

Comment: IRQs are armed at the state of requesting them (i.e. they are **always** armed until you explicitly disable them, see `free_irq()` call somewhere near to the `request_any_context_irq()` in _gpiolib-sysfs.c_). Then it's hardware driven event model.

Comment: `lseek()` and `read()` are necessary in case you need that data, otherwise I think you may ignore that.

Comment: 4.0.0 is actually the Buildroot version, so the kernel is 4.0.

Comment: The question is really this: If one interrupt completes a poll() call, will another interrupt that happens before the lseek() cause the next poll() to complete immediately? How about between lseek() and read()? How about between read() and the next poll()? If an interrupt isn't recognized until after poll() is called again, then there's no reliable way to prevent a lost interrupt.

The reason I ask here is that lost interrupts are the sort of thing that only happens rarely, so it's a hard thing to test.

Comment: Interrupt can happen **any** time, because it's a **hardware interrupt**.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using sysfs recently, and this snippet helped me:

```c
int main() {
    struct pollfd myPollfd;
    myPollfd.fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/GPIO_IN_WHEEL1/value", O_RDONLY); //store filedescriptor in struct, open(path, read-write-permission)
    myPollfd.events = POLLPRI;
    while (1) {
        poll(&myPollfd, 1, -1); //poll(struct pollfd, max fd, timeout), timeout=-1 --> never
        if(myPollfd.revents & POLLPRI) {
            len = read(myPollfd.fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);  //mandatory to make system register interrupt as served
            printf("interrupt!\n",);
        }
        lseek(myPollfd.fd, 0, 0); //return cursor to beginning of file or next read() will return EOF
    }
    close(myPollfd.fd);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the sysfs manual, **it's the read operation that makrs the interrupt to register as served**, so in order to react to the next interrupt one must call read() on the endpoint, even if the content of the endpoint itself is meaningless.

Unfortunately i can't find the said documentation at the moment, but if i understood your question correctly, what you need to know is that all interrupts that happen between the first and the first call to read() are going to be lost.